# Doctrine how to check if record exists when adding item

Tags: doctrine-orm, concrete5

I have a table of states/regions which has 2 fields: state and country, where the country is a reference to the country object in table of countries:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="LocationStates")
 */
class LocationState
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $state_id;

    public function getStateID()
    {
        return $this->state_id;
    }

    public function setStateID($state_id)
    {
        $this->state_id = $state_id;
    }

    /**
     * Many States have one Country
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LocationCountry")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country",referencedColumnName="country_id",onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $country;

    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;
    }
```

I have a single page and controller where a user adds a new state or edits the existing state.

There are the following conditions for the States:

1. Countries are selected from a given set of countries (part of the site engine), a state/region cannot be saved without a selected country
2. There are 2 fields for the state/region: select box populated on selecting a country with known states (e.g. USA, Australia, UK) - not all countries have states, so there is also a text box to enter a region for a country without states
3. When a state is saved, the controller should check if a state with the same name AND country already exists - if yes, then it's an error, you can't have same state names with the same country

If a new state is saved, I check if this state new or existing and if new, then I check if another state exists with the same name and country ID:

```
!is_object(LocationState::getByID($state_id)) && !empty(LocationState::getByState($state, $country_id))
```

So far so good, that works. But problems start when I edit and save an existing state and can't figure out what the logic should be.

If I do this:

```
is_object(LocationState::getByID($state_id)) && LocationState::getByID($state_id)->getState() != $state && !empty(LocationState::getByState($state, $country_id))
```

it checks if it's an existing state, if yes then it checks I changed its name, then it checks if another one with the same name and country ID exists - and this is not working, I can't get the logic right. It only works if the country doesn't change. But if I edit the state, I may want to change its country too. But the above code saves the state with the same name and same country ID as the already existing one.

Here's the getByState() which is part of class LocationState:

```
public static function getByState($state, $country = null)
{
    $em = \ORM::entityManager();
    if (is_null($country)) {
        return $em->getRepository(get_class())->findOneBy(array('state' => $state));
    }
    else {
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        return $qb->select('c')
            ->from('LocationState', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('c.country', 'j', 'WITH', 'j.country_id = c.country')
            ->andWhere('j.country_id = ?1')->setParameter(1, $country)
            ->andWhere('c.state = ?2')->setParameter(2, $state)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Will really appreciate your help with the last bit of logic to save edited state to make sure it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Where’s your getByState method?

Comment: I've updated the post and added the getByState